# How to link a a custom workflow with a content type or an entity?

Tags: 8, entities, workflows

I have a custom entity **booking**.
I created a custom workflow type **booking_moderation** dedicated to this in `Drupal\my_module\Plugin\WorkflowType\BookingModeration`. I could then add my desirated states and transitions via the UI:

[image]

Then I don't understand and I can'f find any documentation about how to properly link this workflow with my custom entity type. I looked at **content_moderation** module to set the configuration form, in order to set my booking content but then i get confused...

[image]

Do I have to create a custom field type (+ formatter and widget) via the field Plugin and handle tables and data by this field?

Or is there a simpler trick that I can't see?!